# Compilation errors for C# code with unicode character set in VS2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Im having problems compiling source code with escaped unicode characters (e.g. `"\u206C"`). Upon compiling, I get *very obvious errors* that the compiler *can't interpret the characters*. How can I *enable unicode* on VS2017, or inform the compiler to interpret them as unicode? Google shows references to project properties to enable unicode character sets but that setting is not present in VS2017 (or at least from what I can find very similar properties).

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: You will probably need to double thel slash or use @ before the string literal.

Comment: For example...

class \u202BxportSettings\u206C
{

...

Comment: What are the errors that you are seeing?

Comment: In the example above, the error is "Identifier expected { expected". Which an open curly brace is present but its obvious VS simply doesn't know how to interpret the unicode escape characters.

Comment: The question is why you want to do this at all? Is this just to satisfy some weird requirement, like creating an assembly with a type with a very specific name? I ask because this has the effect of making your source code really hard to read which is sort of contrary to one of the main rules of writing maintainable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Indentifier* (class name must be an identifier) must *start* with letter or underscope and can *contain* letters, digits and underscopes.

see

https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-334%201st%20edition%20December%202001.pdf

for details (page `55`)

In your case

```
u202B - RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING - is not a letter (or underscope)
```

that's why `@\u202BxportSettings\u206C` is not a *correct identifier* (and doesn't compile). Let's change `u202B` into `u0041` (letter `A`):

```
// This will be compiled
public class @\u0041xportSettings\u206C {
}
```

Comment: Does this imply `202B` is a "digit"?

Comment: @Joe Sewell: `\u202B` see https://codepoints.net/U+206C behaves as Combining Mark (second class "letter" which is not allowed to start the identifier but can appear within it).